# Runge-Kutta 4th order using Python numexpr.evaluate()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numerical-methods, scipy

I am implementing an ODE solver, where the user provides rates and coefficients as a string. ODE solver has to work with vectors.  The best implementation I got so far is the following:

```
# k_1 = dt*dcdt(C0, dt);
# k_2 = dt*dcdt(C0+0.5*k_1, dt);
# k_3 = dt*dcdt(C0+0.5*k_2, dt);
# k_4 = dt*dcdt(C0+k_3, dt);
# C_new = C0 + (k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)/6;

import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

dt = 0.1

coef = {'k': 1}
rates = {'R1': 'k*y1*y2'}
dcdt = {'y1': '-4 * R1', 'y2': '-R1'}
C0 = {'y2': np.random.rand(400), 'y1': np.random.rand(400)}


def k_loop(conc):
    rates_num = {}

    for k in rates:
        rates_num[k] = ne.evaluate(rates[k], {**coef, **conc})

    dcdt_num = {}

    for k in dcdt:
        dcdt_num[k] = ne.evaluate(dcdt[k], rates_num)

    Kn = {}

    for k in C0:
        Kn[k] = dt * dcdt_num[k]
    return Kn


def sum_k(A, B, b):
    C = {}
    for k in A:
        C[k] = A[k] + b * B[k] * dt
    return C


def result(C_0, k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4):
    C_new = {}
    for k in C_0:
        C_new[k] = C_0[k] + (k_1[k] + 2 * k_2[k] + 2 * k_3[k] + k_4[k]) / 6
    return C_new


k1 = k_loop(C0)
k2 = k_loop(sum_k(C0, k1, 0.5))
k3 = k_loop(sum_k(C0, k2, 0.5))
k4 = k_loop(sum_k(C0, k3, 1))

C_new = result(C0, k1, k2, k3, k4)
```

This ODE solver I am planning to use inside of the Object-oriented PDE solver. The PDE solver will provide `C0` vectors. Therefore, the performance is crucial. I used numexpr.evaluate() for simplified user input of the rates. Can it be implemented in vectorized form? If you know the better implementation of the solver with such simplified input, please, let me know.

**Metrics:**

eval():

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 372 µs per loop
```

ne.evaluate():

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 377 µs per loop
```

@Graipher example:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 452 µs per loop
```

Comment: this is python 3.5 syntax.

Comment: Does the use of `np.array` in `C0` do anything for you?  Why not just lists?  I don't see any other use of `numpy` operations.

Comment: Numpy arrays will be the inputs for this module from external PDE solver.

Comment: As a general practice `eval` is considered to be dangerous and slow. `ast.literal_eval` is safer, though my impression is that it may be slower.  `sympy` is another option if you math expressions.  It might help if you gave examples of `rates`.  Just how general do you need to go?

Comment: regarding the examples of the rates, it could be something like ```-0.25 * R8  - 2 * R9  - R1  - 3 * R12``` in the simple case, where R_n will depend on y_1...y_n. In more difficult scenario R  could be proportional to exp or log10,e.g., R1 = k1*y1*y2/(y2+k5)*(1/(exp ( (k2 + k3 * log10(y1/y2))/k4) + 1) .

Comment: How can I implement it using Sympy if I have dict of vectors and coefficients?

Comment: replaced eval() with numexpr.evaluate() for safety.

Comment: Which are these 'vectors of size 300+ elements'?  The match between that statement and your code is not obvious.

Comment: y1 and y2 in C0 and k in coef.

Comment: I think it would help if you could give a more realistic data example. The overhead of using `numpy` and not `dict`s might be large for small values but negligible for large vectors.

Comment: This is very realistic example except for size (will be 300+ elements in the vectors y1, y2). The y1 and y2 will be Numpy vectors for sure (it will be provided by another solver).  I am creating ```dict```for easiness of use by the user.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I would make all objects `numpy` arrays and get the user to use index notation. They would have to write equations of the form `R = np.array(['c[0]*y[0]*y[1]'])` meaning that this will later evaluate just like your `R = {'R1': 'c*y1*y2'}`. Almost all functions can then take advantage of the fact that `numpy` does almost everything vectorized.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# k_1 = dt*dcdt(C0, dt);
# k_2 = dt*dcdt(C0+0.5*k_1, dt);
# k_3 = dt*dcdt(C0+0.5*k_2, dt);
# k_4 = dt*dcdt(C0+k_3, dt);
# C_new = C0 + (k_1+2*k_2+2*k_3+k_4)/6;

import numpy as np

dt = 0.1

c = np.array([1])
y = np.array([[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]])
R = np.array(['c[0]*y[0]*y[1]'])
dcdt = np.array(['-4 * R[0]', '-R[0]'])


def k_loop(y):
    rates_num = np.array([eval(k) for k in R])
    dcdt_num = np.array([eval(k, {'R': rates_num}) for k in dcdt])
    return dt * dcdt_num


def sum_k(A, B, b):
    return A + b * B * dt


def result(y_0, k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4):
    return y_0 + (k_1 + 2 * k_2 + 2 * k_3 + k_4) / 6


k1 = k_loop(y)
k2 = k_loop(sum_k(y, k1, 0.5))
k3 = k_loop(sum_k(y, k2, 0.5))
k4 = k_loop(sum_k(y, k3, 1))

y_new = result(y, k1, k2, k3, k4)
print(y_new)
```

Note that this is slightly slower for the small example given (0.09s vs 0.08s). Also the step `rates_num = np.array([eval(k) for k in R])` looses some precision (up to `1E-4`).

To see whether or not this performs better, a more realistic example would be needed.

The `eval` call can be back-substituted with `ne.evaluate`, I just didn't want to install it.

To calculate timings, I ran the `result` function 100000 times, like so:

```
for _ in range(100000):
    y = result(y, k1, k2, k3, k4)
```

When doing this with your original code, this takes 1.36s, while my code takes 0.99s.

However, when including updating the `k`s, this advantage goes away again:

```
for _ in range(10000):
    k1 = k_loop(y)
    k2 = k_loop(sum_k(y, k1, 0.5))
    k3 = k_loop(sum_k(y, k2, 0.5))
    k4 = k_loop(sum_k(y, k3, 1))
    y = result(y, k1, k2, k3, k4)
```

Note that this is ten times less often than before. Here your code takes 2.7s and my code takes 3.7s on my machine.

Comment: I am getting an error ```NameError: name 'c' is not defined```

Comment: @IgorMarkelov Weird, it works for me. Are you copying the whole code or are you using it along with some other stuff? You might have to use `rates_num = np.array([eval(k, {'c':c, 'y':y}) for k in R])` to make sure they are defined. Or are you not using the latest version of my answer? (I tried to do a vectorized `eval`, which is not a good idea)

Comment: You are correct ```np.array([eval(k, {'c':c, 'y':y}) for k in R])``` solved the problem...

Comment: However, the performance is lower ```1000 loops, best of 3: 449 µs per loop``` compared to my example ```1000 loops, best of 3: 389 µs per loop``` for ```C0 = {'y1': np.random.rand(400,1), 'y2': np.random.rand(400,1)}```.

Comment: @IgorMarkelov Yes, it does seem to be slower on similar examples on my machine, as well.

Comment: The ```k```s should be updated each step.

Answer (score 1):

Not a thorough review but a Small contribution:

The dt term is multiplied by another constant input at each call of the sum_k function. (dt*0.5, etc).

You can get rid of the dt term in the sum_k function, and this would reduce the runtime performance a little bit.